# How to use EasyTracker with application which is having multiple Activities?

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

Can anybody tell me EasyTracker.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).activityStart(this); need to write on every Activities onStart() method. I am using Google analytic v3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Enable auto activity tracking by setting this line in your values/"analytics".xml

```
<!-- Enable Activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
```

and in every activity add this to your onStop

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
```

Comment: you mean ga_autoActivityTracking will track all activities, no need to put code to start track on onStart() method. Is there any way to stop EasyTracker.

Comment: If you mean to stop easytracker permanently, you can remove the sdk, but if you want to temporarily disable it you can close the auto tracking and put a boolean around the onstop line of code.

Comment: It Means EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); needs to be written on every Activities onStop() method.

Comment: Yes ,that is the only thing you have to do in your code and the library does all the other things

Comment: Is this affect my application speed and is throw any exception?

Comment: Not at all . I used it in many apps and never had any problem